# Why Java doesn't make use of encapsulation with some classes?

Tags: java, object-oriented, encapsulation

My question is related with `System.in` and `System.out` classes (there might be others like those in the Standard library). Why is that? Isn't that a bad practice in OOP? Shouldn't it be used like: `System.getIn()` and `System.getOut()`? I've always had this question and I hope I can find a good answer here.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The definition for the `in` and `out` fields within the `System` class are:

```
public final static PrintStream out;
public final static InputStream in;
```

These are constants.  They happen to be objects too, but they are constants.  It is very much the same as the Math class:

```
public static final double E = 2.7182818284590452354;
public static final double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
```

Or in the Boolean class:

```
public static final Boolean TRUE = new Boolean(true);
public static final Boolean FALSE = new Boolean(false);
```

Or in the Color class:

```
public final static Color white     = new Color(255, 255, 255);
public final static Color black     = new Color(0, 0, 0);
public final static Color red       = new Color(255, 0, 0);
```

When accessing a public constant that doesn't change, there isn't a significant advantage to encapsulate it - conceptually or performance based.  Its there.  It isn't going to change.

There is no real difference between `Color.white` and `System.out`.

Comment: Well, I haven't seen it that way, they are constant objects. That's a pretty good explanation.

Comment: @Clawdidr in today's Java, one *might* consider using the `enum` to hold them... though `enum` was new with Java 1.5 (not an option in the 1.0 days).

Comment: Just out of curiosity (not a Java developer myself): is there a difference between `final static` and `static final`? If so what is it?

Comment: @MarjanVenema no difference, just preferred order of the modifiers.  [checkstyle modifier check](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_modifier.html) shows the preferred order.  Apparently, whoever wrote those two source files in the jdk version I have didn't agree on the order.  Its merely convention.

Comment: :) and thanks Michael, for taking the time to respond and for the link.

Comment: What a fantastic way to view it--constant objects.  Never heard it that way before.  Color me impressed.

Comment: Actually, System.in/out/err are not constants. They are a special case ... `static final` variables that can be changed via special methods.

Comment: @StephenC yep, special native methods that dig into the VM itself. Within native methods, the java access control rules (final) are not enforced. Its mentioned in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.4) Section 17.5.4.  This still prevents silly the modification of it (`System.in = foo`) and also has checks against the SecrutiyManager. However, historically (1.0 - `setIn` was added in 1.1) and conceptually, `System.in` and its siblings are best thought of as constants. And given the 1.0 requirements of backwards compatibility, it can't be changed.

Comment: why are some upper case and some lower case?

Comment: @jgauffin poorly formalized standards when they were added?  Color has both.  The line after the `public final static Color white = new Color(255, 255, 255);` in my jdk is `public final static color WHITE = white;`

Answer (score 5):

The real reason is that this is a legacy issue.  The `System.in,out,err` constants were part of Java 1.0 ... and probably a lot further back.  By the time it was clear that the design had problems, it was too late to fix it.  The best they could do was to add the `System.setIn,setOut,setErr` methods in Java 1.1 and then deal with the language specification issues<sup>1</sup>.

This is similar to the issue of why there is a static `System.arraycopy` method whose name violates the Java naming conventions.

---

As to whether this is "bad design" or not, I think it is.  There are situations where the current non-OO handling is a serious problem.  (Think ... how can you run one Java program *inside* another when their "standard IO" stream requirements conflict.  Think ... unit testing code that entails changing the streams.)

However, I can also relate to the argument that the current way of doing things is *more convenient* in a lot of cases.

---

<sup>1 - It is interesting to note that the `System.in,out,err` variables get special mention in the JLS as having "special semantics".  The JLS says that if you change the value of a `final` field, the behaviour is undefined ... except in the case of *these* fields.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I believe the out object is immutable, which makes it somehow safe (this is debatable) for being kept in a public final static field.

Many of the classes in the JDK do not respect the best object-oriented design principles. One reason for this is the fact that they were written almost 20 years ago, when Object-Orientation was only emerging as a mainstream paradigm and many programmers simply were not familiar with them as they are now. A very good example of bad API design is the Date & Time API, which took them 19 years to change...

Comment: I'd make the statement even stronger, a public final variable (static or not) is exactly as "Safe" as a getter and I'd perfer the immutibility over a setter/getter pair.  Setters are just about always a bad idea (Immutable is good--and if it can't be immutable the method that "Sets" it probably deserves a little business logic too), If you need a getter you might as well make it public final, but doing neither is preferable--don't ask a class for it's data, ask a class to do something to it's data.

Comment: @BillK: Yes, also known as the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) (though it's not a law, rather a guideline).

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/208025/31260) is great and true.

I wanted to add that in some cases **compromises** were made for usability's sake.

Objects of type String can be instantiated without new, event when String is not a primitive:

```
String s = "Hello";
```

String being a non-primitive, should be instantiated like this:

```
String s = new String("Hello");          // this also works
```

But the compiler allows for the shorter, less OO option, because String is by far the most widely used class in the API.

Also arrays can be initialized in a non-OO way:

```
int i[] = {1,2,3};
```

Weird enough, **an object is either an instance of a class or an array**. Meaning arrays are a completely separate type of class.

Arrays have a `length` public field which is not a constant. Also there's no documentation on the class arrays are an instance of. ( not to confuse with Arrays class or java.reflect.Array ).

```
int a = myArray.length;    // not length()
```

Comment: Thee are different things - `new String("Hello")` will always create a new String object.  While `String s = "Hello";` will use the interned object.  Compare: `"Hello" == "Hello"` may be true, while `new String("Hello") == new String("Hello")` is always false.  There is compile time optimization magic happening in the first that isn't possible with `new String("Hello")`.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning

Comment: @MichaelT I added some extra wierdiness on arrays, just for completeness' sake.

Comment: Yes, that's also true, the <code>length</code> field in arrays objects are <code>public</code> but not constants.

Comment: @MichaelT: You're right but you say is not a valid reason to object to what the OP is talking about.

Comment: @Tarik I was objecting to the "String being a non-primitive, should be instanciated like this: `String s = new String("Hello");`" which is incorrect.  The shorter option (`String s = "Hello";`) is *more* correct because of string interning.

Comment: With `String`, there is no "more correct" option. Both are correct. Though, as MichaelT says, the shorter one is preferred because of String interning.

Comment: @AndresF. I changed "less correct" for "less OO".

Comment: @user61852: A string literal passed to the `String` constructor must somehow yield a reference to a `String` object before the constructor can do anything with it, so how would assigning that reference to a variable be less OOP-ish than passing it as a constructor parameter?

Comment: @supercat I'm just talking syntax here.