# What are the advantages of a 'pure' object oriented language over a non-pure object oriented language?

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, programming-languages

My first programming language is C++. C++ is a multi-paradigm programming language. One of the paradigms C++ supports is Object Oriented Programming. I want to say I get the general idea and benefits of OOP as is exemplified in C++.

I have recently started creating a project in Android Studio. One of the languages Android Studio supports is Java. Java is a 'pure' object oriented programming language. Pure is in scare quotes due to java supporting primitive data types.

My question is why does Java go full OOP where as C++ doesn't feel the need to go to that extent. C++'s approach seems more 'reasonable' to me. However, I'm sure there are specific reasons why Java does it the way it does. Where everything is an object, everything has to be declared as public, protected, etc. Everything is used loosely.

Comment: Try SmallTalk or Self - Those are Object Orientated languages no scare quotes needed. Java is more Object Orientated than C++ because of garbage collection. The reason why Java requires you to specify scoping (public/private/...) is because Objects are instances of complex types with a complex interface that restrict who can use portions of that interface.  C++ does it too. What are the benefits? *Wrong question.* Which language is more natural for expressing the solution to the problem you have? That depends on the solution.

Comment: It all depends on the philosophy / design principles for a given language, and its evolution. Programming languages (successful ones anyway) are created to solve specific needs.

Comment: What makes Java pure/full OOP as you claim, even though it has primitives?

Comment: See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/240379/

Comment: @Kain0_0 can you expand on this part "Java is more Object Orientated than C++ because of garbage collection". Why does being more object oriented entail a connection with garbage collection, if I'm understanding it correctly.

Comment: The wording of this question is really bad, Java is definitely not a "pure OO language" from an OO purists view (you find a discussion [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-Java-a-pure-object-oriented-programming-language), for example). It may be "more OO than C++" in some sense, whatever that means. Try to improve the wording, then I consider to turn my downvote into an upvote.

Comment: If you want to learn about certain design principles of Java, and why the designers took a different approach than Stroustrup for C++, have a look into [this page from Oracle's Java docs](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/intro-141325.html)

Comment: ... and if you take a look into Bertrand Meyer's "[Principles of language design and evolution](http://se.inf.ethz.ch/~meyer/publications/hoare/evolution.pdf)", you get the impression the author thought Java and C++ are equally crap, and only Eiffel is worth to be called a "real" programming language.

Comment: What are the advantages of a toolbox that has only hammers? I'm sorry, but the more I work with pure languages, less convinced I am that they are superior as their authors/enthusiasts claim. By the end of the day, I just want to go back to my trusty C# and code in whatever paradigm I need _at that moment_ to get the job done. Personally, I want a language that obeys me, and not one that forces me to obey.

Comment: @T.Sar-ReinstateMonica: do you have a specific "pure" language in mind?

Comment: @DocBrown In a professional setting, Haskell. In an academic setting, probably everything under the sun 'cause my current teacher is a sadist.

Comment: RAM machines have addressable memory `0..(2^N)-1`, where `N` is the bit size of the pointer. All memory addresses exist for the duration of the program. No new addresses will ever exist, nor can they be made to not exist. Therefor we must come to some consensus about what is at particular addresses. In C/C++ like languages the language defers that consensus to the programmer. Do you want to change how you look at a section of memory, just change the pointer type. No worries. But this makes GC impossible, without the programmer agreeing to play nice. That's a *huge* loop hole.

Comment: The way to make GC possible is for the language to assume all responsibility for book keeping, and to take away from the programmer the ability to randomly anoite pieces of memory as being of a particular type. The GC can handle most memory itself as it only needs to be deallocated. This is good enough for not objects like `int`, and actual objects like `String`. But not for objects like `File`, these need to do something first. The GC cannot know what that something is in advance so it calls a function called a finaliser. Java provides this via an interface and only objects can implement that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java is indeed more object-oriented than C++:

- Java’s object model is independent of the underlying memory model.
- Some C++ object-oriented features need understanding of the underlying memory model; for example, to dynamically create/delete objects you need pointers or smart pointers and thus make the difference between the address of the object and the object itself. Also, in C++ you can create code independent from any class.

But let’s be provocative: Java is not a pure object oriented language:

- not everything is an object in java: basic types [such as `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7700599/3723423)  are not handled as objects and do not inherit from `Object`. You'd need to use an `Integer` class wrapper to achieve this.
- [static methods](https://www.guru99.com/java-static-variable-methods.html) can be defined in a class but are not bound to any particular object. This feature makes Java more a class-oriented language than an object oriented one.

The increased object orientation has a couple of advantages:

- increased portability (i.e. you just rely on an abstract object model).
- consistency of the language constructs (everything is an object).

I don’t know if there are many pure OO languages out there. [Smalltalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) would be a good candidate. However it requires a paradigm shift, that makes even some simple code difficult to read.

In the end, OO is like oxygen (O₂): in reasonable dose it makes fresh air and enables complex life; in pure concentration it deprives air from other useful things. This certainly contributes to explain the current dominance of multi-paradigm languages.

Comment: Hey, C++ is just as "independent" of the underlying memory model as the Java language. Java just seems like it's independent because it runs in the JVMs memory model. Well [C++ can do that too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4221605/1493294). ;)

Comment: *"But let’s be provocative: java is not a pure object oriented language"* - I found the original claim that java is such a language" way more provocative.

Comment: @candied_orange As a C++ fanatic I’d be (almost) with you. But If you’re in OO, you’ll want sooner or later to use polymorphism. In C++ it requires to understand what a pointer is, and the difference between object and a pointer to the object. You then need to make the difference btw local and free store objects. It’s related to the memory model. I agree, it’s not much to know, but you can’t escape it.  In java, with the reference semantic and uniform object creation and use, you don’t need to know these details at all. When teaching the language, this makes a lot of difference.

Comment: @candied_orange this being said, we can agree that in both languages we can write nice portable OO programs ;-)

Comment: @Christophe As in Java, where you also need to know the difference between a pointer (called reference) and an object. And only having one option is very different from it not making a difference.

Answer (score 6):

The advantage of a 'pure' language of any paradigm is that you (ideally) don't have to keep reminding yourself to follow the paradigm since the language won't let you get anything done if you don't.

For example, Java is a 'pure' structural language. Which is just a fancy way of saying it has no goto. Instead you have while, do while, for, break, and continue. None of which you need if you have goto. It's the things you can't do in a language that make it 'pure'.

So what is that for object oriented languages? Primitives. If you want your language to be purely object oriented everything must be an object. No primitives.

If you find that unsatisfying I don't blame you. OOP's biggest feature is polymorphic message passing but the lack of primitives is what languages need to be considered ['pure' OO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk#Object-oriented_programming).

Sadly this means that even 'pure' OOP languages aren't forcing you to use the best features of OO. They're only forcing you to use the OOP features that can be forced.

Comment: `None of which you need if you have goto` -- You don't need goto either.  You just need recursion and branching.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well no, recursion is only a perfect replacement for goto if you have infinite memory. My bus isn't that wide and my wallet isn't that deep.

Comment: Just use a compiler that has tail call optimization. With tail call optimization, recursive function calls can automatically be transformed into jumps, allowing infinite recursion

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez that would work. But now you've simply created another 'pure' language. Instead of structured programming it's tail call programming.

Comment: Even C++ has tail call optimization as a feature implemented by all major compilers, and C++ is about as far from pure as you can get

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez we're talking about what makes a language 'pure'. Everything ends up as machine language anyway so it's pointless to argue that an impure language exists. The purity is just for us humans. Computers don't care.

Comment: My point though is that *because* everything ends up as machine language, recursion with tail call optimization is a perfect replacement for the use of goto.

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez If it was structured programming wouldn't exist. All you're offering is a different paradigm that would also keep goto's spaghetti code at bay.

Comment: The logic of this answer is IMHO flawed, or at least a little bit naive. Developers with no OO training (or simply beginners) find a lot of ways to write procedural code in Java, and that has nothing to do with the availability of primitives. You could forbid usage of primitives, but that would not make such code more OO. Or, citing Dijkstra, [you can write FORTRAN in any language](https://blog.codinghorror.com/you-can-write-fortran-in-any-language/)

Comment: @DocBrown I can't disagree with your criticism. But I feel the flaw lies with the very concept of 'pure OO language'. Point me to one single 'pure' OO language that will keep a determined programmer from coding procedurally. I'll adopt it today.

Comment: @DocBrown That happens because in the end all languages are just abstractions of other languages. [A very determined person can cook up a VM on minecraft](https://www.businessinsider.com/virtual-computers-built-inside-minecraft-2015-2), even. With enough boilerplate, we can write anything, anywhere.

Comment: @T.Sar-ReinstateMonica: my point was not what experienced people can do in theory, but what unexperienced people actually **do** in reality. Let me phrase it this way: even if a programming language follows an "OO paradigm", this does not make it really hard for users of that language (especially beginner users) to write non-OO programs. This answer gives me the impression of telling readers a different story.

Comment: @DocBrown my answers point is that even under the definition, and best examples of, pure OO languages this is all you get. You're saying that not what it should be. I agree with you. But this is what it is. We simply don't have that. Pure OO isn't nearly as cool as pure structural. The "purity" of OO languages is a pale imitation.  Thus we have to instill OO in the programmer. Like I said, this situation is not satisfying.

Comment: @DocBrown Hm... Yeah, I think I can see what you mean, now. You have a good point.

Comment: @candied_orange: call me nitty, but I think your answer would improve heavily when you change the first sentence to something like "... that you (ideally) don't have to keep reminding ...". Let me add, I don't see it as a problem that just providing a "perfect programming language" (whatever this could be) does not make everyone a perfect programmer.

Comment: @DocBrown better?

Comment: Sure (+1), but I guess it makes sense when I don't delete my former comments this time.

Comment: @DocBrown one thing I've been trying to figure out how to work in is Uncle Bob once defined OOPs defining feature to be "being formal about function pointers" (which I can appreciate after seeing their syntax in c, yuck) but I've never seen anyone list that as a requirement for a 'pure' OO language.

Comment: @candied_orange: you meant [this blog post](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/11/24/FPvsOO.html), I guess? As I understand it, this is just a fancy way of saying "an OO language needs to abstract function pointers away by providing means for polymorphism" - and that is pretty much what you mentioned in your answer as "OOPs biggest feature".

Comment: @DocBrown right, but is that an actual requirement of 'pure' OO languages? Not asking if it should be. Asking if the acknowledged 'pure' OO languages actually do prevent you from using any other form of function pointer. Because if so then I missed an enforced feature.

Comment: @DocBrown & candied_orange: The way I see modern OOP languages is: originally, you had the concept of a "message" as an abstraction of a direct function call, the message being a token that has a well defined meaning as an operation, but that's interpreted as a concrete function by the target object. Then strongly typed languages took that idea and imposed structure in the form of inheritance, codified the form of the message token, and took over control of the dispatch mechanism and instance data storage - which is fine in most scenarios.

Comment: In some scenarios, though, the ability to control how the instances are stored is important, which is why the game industry came up with ECS, it seems. P.S. See the Message passing section (scroll to the bottom of the page) in [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-17.html#%_sec_2.4.3) - it's Lisp, but, if you can't read it, the text explains it pretty well.

Comment: P.P.S. Note that with this message as a token idea, you have polymorphism even without any form of inheritance and delegation (essentially, it's like duck typing), because client code is written in terms of those messages.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović: -The fact one can emulate OO in Scheme in an elegant manner does not hide that Scheme is not a pure OO language  - it is actually not even an OO language ;-)

Comment: @candied_orange: AFAIK older versions of Java did not provide any means of lambda expressions or C#-like delegates. So if one wanted a "function pointer", one had to use objects & polymorphism, there was not other mechanism (except reflection, but I guess that does not count). If that's what you think is what makes "pure OO", then older Java versions were indeed "nearer to pure OO".

Comment: @DocBrown: I didn't say it's a pure OO (or an OO) lang. - I don't care about that, nor did I mean to say anything about Scheme specifically. It was a remark on what OOP itself is (in a more fundamental way then "imposed discipline on function pointers"); getting the inbuilt language mechanisms designed to support OOP out of the picture helps with that insight. The interesting thing about that chapter is that they discuss 3 ways to represent abstractions, irrespective of language: "intelligent operations" (ADTs) vs "intelligent data objects" (OOP) vs what they call "data-directed programming".

Comment: @FilipMilovanović: I guess one should not take Uncle Bob's [blog post](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/11/24/FPvsOO.html)  about function pointers too literal. He was obviously oversimplifying to make a point in the context of that blog post, and I am pretty sure he is aware of the SICP approach to OO (as well as other approaches). Note also there are several [object-oriented successors of Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp_Object_System#CLOS_in_other_programming_languages) following the CLOS approach which surely deserve the attribute "OO language" ...

Comment: ... and it is probably of less importance for an "OO language" or "pure OO language" what mechanism is "abstracted away" in its implementation of polymorphism. Let us not forget the original question was "what is the point of a pure OO language over a multi-paradigm language", so if you know a "pure OO language" developed out of the Scheme or Lisp family of languages, and can tell us some benefits or disadvantages over classic Scheme or Lisp, feel free to post an answer and tell us your experience with that.

Comment: @DocBrown: you are right to point out that we should not forget the original question, but your discussion with candied_orange came down to (1) what is OOP in its core, and (2) how that fits into the notions of an "OO language" and a "pure OO language". Assuming (hypothetically) that we can agree on (1), then an OOP lang is anything that offers in-built mechanisms for some form of (1). As for "pure" - the notion is ill-defined, and flawed in the sense that "pure" suggests something good in itself, when it's in fact just a design restriction, and its utility depends on other factors. 1/2

Comment: So the answer to "what are the advantages of a 'pure' object oriented language" depends heavily on what 'pure' actually means, and that is a whole different problem. Furthermore, as pointed out in this answer "Sadly this means that even 'pure' OOP languages aren't forcing you to use the best features of OO", but it's even worse than that - OO design is a skill, and no amount of language features/restrictions can make up for it. Also, I know comments are not for extended discussion, but here we are :) 2/2

Comment: I put this discussion [to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101269/discussion-between-doc-brown-and-filip-milovanovic).

Answer (score 2):

A key consideration in language design is complexity. How many features does the language have? How hard is it to learn? By reducing the number of features, you usually make the language easier to learn.

**By following a single paradigm, you can can remove features.**

Then there's program design. As a programmer, you have to think about how to structure your program. If your programming language gives you lots of flexibility in the structure, you may arrive at a better design in the end, but you also have to think through more possibilities. Working in a more constrained language often feels more productive (and might even be), because even if your design isn't as optimal as one you could have achieved in a more flexible language, you arrived there faster.

**By following a single paradigm, you streamline the application design process.**

As a consequence, then, if there are fewer possibilities for application design, if you encounter an unfamiliar codebase, it should be easier to understand its design, as there are only so many possibilities. This makes it easier to introduce new programmers to the development team.

**By following a single paradigm, you narrow the design space, thus making onboarding of new team members easier.**

Comment: This looks like a good start for an answer. Now explain how this maps to the design of Java and give some examples where these ideas were applied in the design of the language - then it could become a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Java and C++, C++ was based on C, so all the non-OO stuff was there for free. Removing it would have cost time and money, and would have made it much harder to move software from C to C++.

In the case of Java, they would have had to add extra work in the language, compiler, virtual machine, to make non-OO code work. JNI is kind of non-OO and that was only added later.